# Code to auto-create and auto-assign Instance arguments to objects

Tags: python, class, for-loop, object, oop

I am trying to do the object creating and auto value assigning through `for`-loop, seems it's working good inside the loop. But I'm unable to use the `clienta`, `clientb` outside of the loop any more, it says undefined name. My intention was to create objects like below, without actually creating them manually.

```
clienta = customer(10,5,'cement',8,'Y')
clientb = customer(6,1,'Amber',8,'Y')
clientc = customer(8888,443,'print',2,'N')
```

Below is my code:

```
class customer:
    def __init__(self, Coverage, Home, Type, Units, Discounted):
        self.Coverage = Coverage
        self.Home = Home
        self.Type = Type
        self.Units = Units
        self.Discounted = Discounted

    def Final_Amount(self, Premium):
        Final_Amount = Premium * self.Coverage * self.Home * self.Type * self.Units


import json

with open(r"C:\path\abc.json") as json_file:
    data = json.loads(json_file.read())
    resp = data["requests"]
    print(resp)

for x in resp:
    print(x)
    a = (resp[x]).split("+")
    resp[x] = customer(a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4])
    print(resp[x].Home)
```

Data in `abc.json` is like below:

[image: screenshot of json data]

So, finally I am expecting to call the object as `clientb.Final_Amount(350)`,  `clienta.Final_Amount(1000)`, or `clientc.Final_Amount(350)`.

But I am unable to call the `clienta`, `clientb` outside of the loop any more, it says `undefined name`.

Comment: Don't post images of textual data — copy and paste it *into* your questions.

Comment: Also see [Why you don't want to dynamically create variables](https://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html).